# how to fix Issue with codeigniter 4 after pushing to live server

Tags: php, server, localhost, issue-tracking, codeigniter-4

After building my website on `localhost` it works fine but when I launched it to a live server, the homepage displays, and few other pages as others couldn't. Please can someone help me out?

I got this error

```
   rewind($this->fileHandle);
207         }
208 
209         $session_data = '';
210         clearstatcache();    // Address https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/issues/2056
211         for ($read = 0, $length = filesize($this->filePath . $sessionID); $read < $length; $read += strlen($buffer))
212         {
213             if (($buffer = fread($this->fileHandle, $length - $read)) === false)
214             {
215                 break;
216             }
217 
218             $session_data .= $buffer;
219         }
```

and this

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ErrorException: Unknown: Cannot call session save handler in a recursive manner in Unknown:0 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: CodeIgniter\Debug\Exceptions->errorHandler(2, 'Unknown: Cannot...', 'Unknown', 0, NULL) #1 {main} thrown in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Make sure you have edited the app/Config/App.php and app/Config/Database.php files with your live server details

Comment: yes done already

Comment: Check the logs in your writeable folder on the live server. That may shed some light.

Comment: What do you mean by display? Kindly explain your problem or error you're facing. Explain what have you tried so far.

Comment: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: Which version of CI4 are you using? Also what version of PHP are you using on your local and host Servers. If it worked on your local host then the difference is on the hosted server. So what is different?